# Bokeh image section

Tags: python, bokeh

I am using bokehjs from python in order to display 2d gl array as images or heat map.
Generally, in different tools i know, In order to explore the data there is a popular data analysis feature of "section" that you mark on the image and see a 1d graph of the image gl.
Does it exist on bokeh?
If not, what is the best choice of creating it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Do you have 2d data for which you want to select a 1d 'slice' and display it as a graph? Or do you have a 3d cube of data for which want to display a 2d (x,y) image and for a point a graph (z)?

Either way, for sure it's possible with Bokeh, but not out-of-the-box (for as far as i know).

Maybe you are better of looking at project like Holoviews (or its Geoviews) and see if that works for your use case. Holoviews has several backends for rendering, for example one for Bokeh.

See for example the "More detailed example" at their website, move the slider on the right side of the plot for some interactivity:

http://holoviews.org/

Comment: thanks Rutger.
I meant slicing 2d data into 1d graph.

Comment: thanks Rutger.
I meant slicing 2d data into 1d graph.
I looked at holoviews example but I am more looking to extend plotting tools like zoom, pan, or hover (http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html) with this 1d section capability.